# Preserving a wielded corpse without tinning

Tags: nethack

The end-game, I've discovered, is made much, much easier by wielding a chicka/cockatrice corpse and stoning everything in my path.

Is there any way to prevent such a corpse from rotting away, while still maintaining its status as a wieldable weapon?

Comment: I once wielded a knight corpse I found on the Valley of the Dead, who I named *Sir Gallant the Totally Not Rotting*, and even ascended with him, but that was because of a weird bug involving corpses on that floor. Alas, my biggest regret was not discovering his potential as a bludgeon until after I had already defeated Vlad. I don't know that one can get a more legitimately unrotting corpse though, short of carrying an ice box around with you.

Comment: Does it retain its properites if you turn it to stone?

Comment: @Zibbobz I could make long notes about corpses and statues (namely that you can't petrify corpses and statues don't retain the traits of their base creature while they are still statues), but the most relevant point is that a chicka/cockatrice is immune to petrification to begin with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prevent rotting by storing a corpse in an ice box or slow rotting by leaving it on an ice square, but that's hardly conducive towards you using it as a weapon. There are very few options open if you want to be able to keep your cockatrice corpse as a usable weapon.

One thing you can try, though, is to reanimate it every now and then, kill it again, and hope it drops a fresh corpse.

Comment: Ice box is basically the closest one can get, and it basically only serves as a "Keep it from rotting when I'm not actively wielding it". Which can be fine if you have a good amount of them to stash... but the main problem is that an ice box has a weight of 900. Which is huuuge.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame.  Such a fun weapon...I didn't even realize that I had petrified Vlad until I saw his statue...

Comment: One day I will play the endgame carrying nothing but an ice box full of chickatrice corpses, some gloves, and the amulet... But that day is not today. :)